# colapse multiple columns values into 1 factor

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

Is there a function to collapse several columns values into 1 factor?
Every record has exactly 1 TRUE value for columns 2:4.
The resulting value for a record should be the column's name which has the true value.

input data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(user=c(1,2,3,4), blue=c(T,F,T,F), green=c(F,F,F,T), red=c(F,T,F,F))

  user  blue green   red
1    1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2    2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
3    3  TRUE FALSE FALSE
4    4 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Expected output:

```
  user color
1    1  blue
2    2   red
3    3  blue
4    4 green
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cbind(data[1], color = apply(data[-1], 1, function(x) names(data[-1])[x]))
  user color
1    1  blue
2    2   red
3    3  blue
4    4 green
```

Answer (score 2):

Advice you to have a look at `gather` function in `tidyr` package.

```
require("tidyr")
require("dplyr")
data %>% gather(color, TF, -user) %>% filter(TF == T) %>% select(-TF) %>% arrange(user)
#   user color
# 1    1  blue
# 2    2   red
# 3    3  blue
# 4    4 green
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
data$named.colors <- factor(apply(data[,2:4], 1, function(row) which(row == T)), labels = c("blue", "green", "red"))
```

It loops over each row, and finds the column that is true, then turns it into a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the **qdapTools** package that I maintain:

```
library(qdapTools)
data[["color"]] <- unlist(counts2list(data[-1]))

##   user  blue green   red color
## 1    1  TRUE FALSE FALSE  blue
## 2    2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE   red
## 3    3  TRUE FALSE FALSE  blue
## 4    4 FALSE  TRUE FALSE green
```

If you want just `user` and `color` use `data[c(1, 5)]`